# Prevent Salesforce users from "seeing one another"

Tags: profile, user-management

I have created an app which two different user profiles have access to. I do not want users from profile A to interact with users from profile B.

How can I ensure that users from different profiles will not see one another on Chatter or find one another by people search?

Both profiles are given "Read Only" permissions for all objects.

Answer (score 5):

It says this in the Summer 13 release notes:
"When your organization has Communities enabled, User Sharing lets you control which other users Community members can see. You can control community members’ access to both internal and external users."

But it sounds like there might be an option without communities:
**User Sharing for internal users is also available through a pilot program. For more information on enabling User Sharing for internal users, contact salesforce.com.**

Comment: I'm part of the User Sharing pilot. It should do exactly what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 2):

If this is specifically about Chatter and the users are in the same Chatter (org, community, whatever) I do not think it is possible. When we previously evaluated Chatter licenses before Communities that was a showstopper for us.

With Communities you might be able to do it if Profile A are in Community 1 and Profile B in Community 2.

Comment: Yes, Chatter is my largest concern. I will look into Communities and see if that is a fitting solution.